# setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically cant be set under iPhone <5 devices

Tags: api, ios6, location, tracking, iphone-4

i have some trouble with my location services...
I figured out a strategy for my needs that works fine on iPhone 5 Devices... 
The case is - user get at work -> gps Hardware should power down -> get wake up when moving on. For this iam using the setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically delegate stuff. But for wake up i use own strategies.

I tested all on the iPhone 5 in my Company, works great - now i made a bigger test with 8 guys and all iPhone 4 guys did cry...

Someone has an option to enable that on iPhone4 ?

```
    if(isIOS6) {
        [m_locationManager setActivityType:CLActivityTypeFitness];
        [m_locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
        [m_locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:YES];

        logff(@"autopause flag %i",[m_locationManager pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically]);
```

}

this code shows me, that i set the flag on a iphone 4 and the api ignores that or changes it back to NO....  what kind of consistent api shit is that ?...

maybe someone can help
greetings and thx guys

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([m_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:)]) {
    [m_locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:YES];
}
```